# Artifacts when using a large texture atlas in libGDX

Tags: opengl, libgdx, lwjgl, visual-artifacts

So, we're using a pretty large texture atlas to do some of the heavy lifting. We have *a lot* of art assets, and we're breaking them up and packing them with the texturepacker. The problem is, when this textureAtlas is invoked in-game, it causes all kinds of havoc with the graphics, the biggest problem being that fonts don't draw properly at all. Now forget getting anything from the textureatlas in question to draw either, that causes all kinds of pacman bug looking stuff to draw. It's not pretty.

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about a fix here? Ideally we'd like to be able to still use the texture atlas.

Here's the line of code that changes in the before/after:

```
backgroundAtlas = new TextureAtlas(new FileHandle(new File(bgPackPath)));
```

Edit: Also getting this console error
"radeon: The kernel rejected CS, see dmesg for more information."

Here's a screenshot of before and after.

Before:
http://s29.postimg.org/hgkfdg5if/before.png

After:
http://s8.postimg.org/5iamym4zp/after.png

Comment: Before and after what change? Is the before picture with no atlas at all? This looks to me like a nearest min filter is being used on a texture that's getting drawn smaller than its original size. Or it could be an issue with a texture being loaded on the wrong thread or something.

Comment: Before instantiating the large texture atlas and after. I'll edit and post code.

Comment: Also added a console message that gets thrown.

Comment: I should add that none of the textures in the texture atlas are being drawn. All that code is commented out right now. The only thing that happens is that the texture atlas is instantiated.

Comment: Wow just a straight up down vote with no comments or anything?

Comment: That's lame. :/ I just thought of something. Is the texture size of the atlas pages bigger than 2048? Maybe some devices react strangely to that.

Comment: I have another texture atlas with fairly large pages, larger than that for sure, so that can't be it.

Comment: I think I might have just run out of memory with my crappy laptop video card linux drivers. We're working on a scheme to reduce the memory textures use by about 75%.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Just crappy linux video drivers and running out of memory. Reducing memory usage solved the issue.